# Scan a specific div and show the 3 most used words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my markup:

```
<body>
  <div id="headbox">
    <p>Whatever...</p>
  </div>
    <div id="feed">
    <div>
    <p>I hate cats</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>I like cats</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>I like cats</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>I like cats</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The deal is I need a script that counts all words which appear in the `<div id="feed">`.

The output should be wrapped in `<p>` tags or `<span>` tags.

```
<h3>The top 3 used words in this feed:</h3>
1.&nbsp;<p>cats</p>&nbsp;4x
2.&nbsp;<p>like</p>&nbsp;3x
3.&nbsp;<p>hate</p>&nbsp;1x
```

This would be the output.

As you can see the word (or better the letter) `I` was not considered. Every word under 3 letters will be not considered by the counting.

Comment: Have you tried `I like turtles`?

Comment: Yes. Turtles make great pets. You should try turtles. :)

Comment: Not to be a jerk but this question deserves to be downvoted because it "does not show any research effort".  Come on, Tomkay, you've gotta at least try *something*...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just loop through the innerHTMLs, split the text on spaces, and use each value of the resulting array to add to or update a master array indexed by the words found with values being the counts of the words.

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest a master object rather than a master array.

Comment: @nnnnnn, My only concern about an object is tallying words like `it's` and other contractions. The apostrophe is not allowed in property names.

Comment: What? No custom script that i can just copy & paste?

Comment: @Tomkay, You bet. Just message me your credit card number and it'll be there. :)  You can do it, man. Just give it a try.

Comment: @Jonathan M: It is: `var o = {}; o["it's"] = 123;`.

Answer (score 5):

Split the inner text of the target element by whitespace, count the word frequency, sort by most frequent, and format the top 3 per your requirements.

Something like this (untested):

```
var getMostFrequentWords = function(words) {
  var freq={}, freqArr=[], i;
  // Map each word to its frequency in "freq".
  for (i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    freq[words[i]] = (freq[words[i]]||0) + 1;
  }
  // Sort from most to least frequent.
  for (i in freq) freqArr.push([i, freq[i]]);
  return freqArr.sort(function(a,b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });
};
var words = $('#feed').get(0).innerText.split(/\s+/);
var mostUsed = getMostFrequentWords(words);
// Now you can prepare "mostUsed.slice(0,3)" as the top 3 words/count.
```

You'll need to modify it to reject words shorter than 3 characters but you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = document.getElementById('myDiv').textContent.split(' ');
var words = {};
text.forEach(function(n, i, ary){
    if(n.length > 3) {
        words[n] = (words[n] || 0) + 1;
    }
});
```

That's what I would do to sort the words. And in the HTML somewhere I will have an ol element for auto-numbering

```
var ol = document.getElementById('myOl');
var sorted_words = [];
for(var i in words) if(words.hasOwnProperty(i) {
    sorted_words.push([i, words[i]]);
}
sorted_words.sort(function(a, b){
    return  b[0] - a[0];
})
.reverse()
.slice(0, 3)
.forEach(function(n, i, ary){
    var li = document.createElement('li')
            .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
            .textContent = n[1] + " " + n[0] + "x";
    ol.appendChild(ul);
});
```

Something like this should work...